# Android application not running on Mac

Tags: android

i have made an android application on my windows machine. Now i am trying to test the application on my Mac. Everytime i do this i enounter the following problem:

**how i do it**
i copy pasted my project onto my mac desktop.
i imported the project into my Eclipse.

My application uses internet connection.Hence i have added the necessary permissions in my android.manifest file for accessing internet. I have tried and tested my app on emulator on windows system many times. But now if i run the same on my mac, the emulator gives connection error (hostunresolved exception)

**another problem**
when i try and change the OS version of Android on my project: By default my app has Android 2.2, when i change it to 2.1, it gives a *.classpath* file not found error and my app starts to have many errors.

what could be the reasons for the above happening?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will work fine in Mac...

May be their is no internet connection on simulator..thats y you getting that error
Check a url in ur browser....Also did you try clean the project after changing the OS version